# how to get a property of all records in django sqlite3

Tags: python, django, sqlite

My model

```
class Article(models.Model) :
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    category = models.CharField(max_length = 50, blank = True)
    date_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    content = models.TextField(blank = True, null = True)

    def __unicode__(self) :
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-date_time']
```

How to make a list contain all category and without repeat?

using the syntax just like:

```
post_list = Article.objects.filter(category__iexact = tag)
```

Comment: this `set(Article.objects.filter(category__iexact = tag))`

Comment: _make a list contain all category_ ... Do you want to find all possible categories?

Comment: sorry, but i am not looking for a category__iexact = tag, i want all category in a list, without repeat

Comment: yes i want to find all possible categories

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `values_list` to extract all values of a particular field.

```
category_list = Article.objects.values_list('category', flat=True)
```

To remove duplicates from the list:

```
categories = list(set(category_list))
```

or as [@Iain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548562/iain-shelvington) pointed out, you can use `.distinct()`

```
category_list = Article.objects.values_list('category', flat=True).distinct()
```

Comment: You can use `distinct()` on a values list rather than `list(set())`

Comment: you are the man!  i have been trying to looking for it in django doc, but i can't made it when reading the huge doc in a short time ( ▼-▼ )

Answer (score 0):

The feature you are looking for is [`distinct`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#distinct). Since it filter in the database layer, it should be faster than filter in Python code

```
post_list = Article.objects.filter(category__iexact = tag).distinct()
```

Answer (score 0):

For all categories for which at least one article exists, you can do:

```
Category.objects.filter(article_set__isnull=False).distinct()
```

This will also give you a `QuerySet` which you can use for further queries unlike a `list`.